Counting with coefficient of an expression

In an examination, the score in each of the four languages – English, Math, Science and Arts- can be integers between $0$ and $10$. Then what is the number of ways in which a student can secure a total score of $21$?


The solution said that it is equivalent to finding the coefficient of $x^{21}$ in $(1+x+x^{2}+x^3 + ...+ x^{10})^4$, but how are they equivalent? How does the coefficient has anything to do at all with our problem?

This is a routine Stars and Bars problem.  As to the generating function, imagine that each of the four factors (your polynomial is raised to the fourth power) represents it's own language, and the exponent of $x$ in that factor is your score in that language.  Note:  for this sort of problem, I think Stars and Bars is considerably easier to apply, but generating functions can be a powerful tool.

@lulu ok after thinking, I think I do get why we are looking at the power of $x^{21}$, I also do get the utility of considering all the powers of $x$ upto 10, but the only thing I think I don't understand,is why at the end we exponentiate the expression to the power $4$? I mean I do get the number of subjects is $4$ among which our score is distributed, but how does that correspond to exponentiating to the power 4?

Because you need one factor for each score.  The coefficient of $x^{21}$ in the final product is the number of ways to write $21$ as the sum of $4$ non-negative integers, which is exactly what you want.

Think of each power of $x$ as standing for a possible score in a given test. It is possible to get a score of anywhere from $0$ to $10$, which correspond to the terms from $1$ to $x^{10}$. As for the exponent of $4$, that corresponds to the fact that there are $4$ subjects on which the students are being tested. We are interested in the coefficients of these terms because they are equal to the number of times their respective power of $x$ occurs in the expansion of the given expression.
Since we have designated each power of $x$ to mean a possible score on a test and we constructed the expression to reflect the fact there are $4$ tests, the coefficient of $x^{21}$ therefore has the interpretation of being the number of ways one can achieve a score of $21$ among $4$ tests.
